# How to get url of the current suitelet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am working with suitescript 2.0, I need to know if there is a way to get the url of the suitelet while running?

Comment: You should be able to use the N/url module - see SuiteAnswers ID 44703.  If you've tried that and are having trouble with it, add some more details about what you've tried and the specific issue you're having.

Answer (score 3):

For the external url you'd do something like this:

```
require(['N/runtime', 'N/url'], function(runtime, url){
    var cs = runtime.getCurrentScript();
    var scriptURL = url.resolveScript({
      scriptId: cs.id,
      deploymentId: cs.deploymentId,
      returnExternalURL: true
    });
```

If you get the internal url you may also have to add host and scheme to the returned root-relative value. In release 2017.1 url will have a url.resolveDomain method that will let you lookup the host.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onRequest(context) {
          log.debug({
    title: 'context',
    details: context.request.method
});
      if (context.request.method === 'GET') {
 fil = context.request.parameters.employee
        log.debug({
    title: 'url',
    details: fil
});
 }
```

This will do ..........
If you are looking to get the Parameter of your Script while it is running or being called.